# Generate file name with format A_B_23/05/2019 is creating subfolders

Tags: java

I am trying to generate a file name with format A_B_23/05/2019.zip however, it is creating a sub folder for each / in the dd/MM/yyyy.

```
StringBuilder sb = null;
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

sb = new StringBuilder("A"+ UNDERSCORE);
sb.append("B");
sb.append(UNDERSCORE);
sb.append(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

How can i generate A_B_23/05/2019.zip without creating sub folder 05?

Comment: I hate to be the "XY" problem guy, but why do you need to have a "/" in the file name? Why can't you encode the date with "-" instead? Filenames like that ***not only break this code, they will also likely break innumerable other programs that would need to work with that file in the future, possibly Windows systems stuff***. For that matter, it's possible OS woldn't let you create such a file name in the first place, Java or not.

Comment: I don't think any major file system allows `/` in filenames.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and possibly `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Consider using ISO 8601 format in your file name. Then you have `A_B_2019-03-23.zip`. `LocalDate.toString` produces ISO 8601 without any explicit formatter.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot use slashes in filenames in Windows or Unix-like systems, as they represent filepaths. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file

> Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), except for the following:
>
> The following reserved characters:
>
> < (less than)
>    > (greater than) 
>    : (colon) 
>   " (double quote) 
>   / (forward slash) 
>   \ (backslash) 
>   | (vertical bar or pipe) 
>   ? (question mark) 
>   * (asterisk)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a  "/" character in your filename. You should choose a 'better' (ie. allowable) way to encode your filenames. As mentioned by @DVK, a "-" is likely a better option (and ISO date formatting compliant!).